# Python dataset aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have a dataset as follows, stored in `pd.DataFrame` object:

```
df

    topic  student level week
 1   sun      a       1     1
 1   sun      b       2     1
 1   moon     a       3     1
 2   tree     a       1     2
 2   tree     b       2     2
 2   tree     a       3     2
 2   tree     b       4     2
 3   cloud    c       1     2
 3   cloud    b       2     2
 3   cloud    c       3     2
 3   cloud    a       4     2
 3   house    b       5     2
```

I would like to aggregate per `id` containing columns as number of students and number of messages.

```
id  topic  num_students num_messages
 1   sun      2            2
 1   moon     1            1
 2   tree     2            4
 3   cloud    3            4
 3   house    1            1
```

Where `num_students` is the number of unique `student` in `df1` per id/topic pair, and `num_messages` the number of id/topic pair.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What are you using to store your dataset? Pandas, NumPy? Also, what have you tried and why is it not working?

Comment: @DavidG pandas!

Comment: Have you even try to do smthg ? What are `num_students`, `num_message` ? Please try to make your problem clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with function [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
d = {'nunique':'num_students','size':'num_messages'}
df1 = (df.groupby(['id','topic'], sort=False)['student']
         .agg(['nunique','size'])
         .rename(columns=d)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   id  topic  num_students  num_messages
0   1    sun             2             2
1   1   moon             1             1
2   2   tree             2             4
3   3  cloud             3             4
4   3  house             1             1
```